# Why we need an empty Constructor to passing/save a Data From Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

maybe this question little bit easy, but I don't get any idea why we need an empty constructor to passing a data from Firebase. Here is an example for the code:

```
public class Hero{
String Name, Weapon, Description, Price, Discount, Id;

public Hero() {
}

public Hero(String name, String weapon, String description, String price, String discount, String id) {
    Name = name;
    Weapon= weapon;
    Description = description;
    Price= price;
    Discount = discount;
    Id= id;
}}
```

then we need a getter and setter for each Menu..

But whats make dizzy is, Why we need an empty Constructor? Is that really necessary?

Can we just make a class without typing an empty constructor? is this will be the same result?

Comment: Note that you don't need getters and setters. Setters are always optional 
- without them Firebase will simply directly modify the field. If you make the fields `public`, the getters are optional too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields of the class will be filled in using reflection. But you cannot create a "default" object (meaning: with no fields pre-filled) without a constructor. Firebase cannot figure out on its own what your constructor does, so that's why you need an empty constructor: to allow Firebase to create a new instance of the object, which it then proceeds to fill in using reflection.

This is not specific to Firebase: you'll find the empty constructor everywhere where a framework or library fills in an object for you, such as JPA/Hibernate.

Edit: for completeness' sake, as @Lutzi mentioned, once you define your own constructor, the default empty constructor that Java defines is no longer available to you, which is why you need to define it explicitly.

Comment: Wow Such A really really helping Answer, Now I got the point of why we need an empty constructor in some using of framework/ library on android Studio. thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

When you create a model class for Firebase, example:

```
public class Chat {
private String mName;
private String mMessage;
private String mUid;

public Chat() {}  // Needed for Firebase

public Chat(String name, String message, String uid) {
    mName = name;
    mMessage = message;
    mUid = uid;
}

public String getName() { return mName; }

public void setName(String name) { mName = name; }

public String getMessage() { return mMessage; }

public void setMessage(String message) { mMessage = message; }

public String getUid() { return mUid; }

public void setUid(String uid) { mUid = uid; }
}
```

1. The getters and setters follow the [JavaBean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) naming pattern which allows Firebase to map the data to field names (ex: getName() provides the name field).
2. The class has an empty constructor, which is required for Firebase's automatic data mapping.

If the class is constructed like the above, Firebase can perform automatic serialization in `DatabaseReference#setValue()` and automatic deserialization in `DataSnapshot#getValue()`.

more info here:

[FirebaseUI README](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)

[setValue() Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Firebase, but I can answer you in a global way. You don't **need** an empty constructor. But if you define a constructor with parameters, then the default empty constructor will be overwritten. This means that you will never be able to call an empty constructor, unless you define yourself the empty constructor. To summary :

If you define any constructor that is not the empty constructor, the default empty constructor provided by Java will no more be "callable".

Answer (score 0):

When the Firebase Realtime database SDK deserializes objects that are coming from the database, it requires that any objects in use, to have a public `no-argument constructor`, so it can use it to instantiate the object. Fields in the objects are set by using public setter methods or direct access to public members.

JavaBeans [require a no-argument constructor](https://coderanch.com/t/634008/java/java-bean-blank-arg-constructor) to be present but when a Java class has no constructors at all, there is a default no-arg constructor automatically added to it by the compiler. The moment you define any constructor in the class (with one or more arguments), the default no-arg constructor goes away and there is no need to define it anymore.

In your code, your `Hero` class defines such a constructor that contains arguments:

```
public Hero(String name, String weapon, String description, String price, String discount, String id) {}
```

As long as this constructor is present, you don't need define a no-arg constructor.

Also please note that setters and getter are also not required. Setters are always optional because if there is no setter for a JSON property, the Firebase client will set the value directly onto the field. A constructor-with-arguments is also not required. Both are idiomatic and there are good cases to have classes without them. If you make the fields public, the getters are optional too.