# How to get data from current logged in user Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all data from currently logged in user in my apps but when I get into the activity that supposed to show the data, the app stopped working. I have set up my Firebase correctly following the guide from Firebase website, I can login with authentication, save data into firebase, and also show all the data, but now i want to show only the data from currently logged in user.

Here is my activity that supposed to show the data

```
public class RsolverAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    TextView showEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rsolveraccount);

        setWidget();
        showData();
    }

    private void showData () {
        DatabaseReference mDatabase;
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userdesc : "+ firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                showEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
   }

    public void setWidget() {
        showEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showEmail);
    }
}
```

this is my Json Tree

```
sraboetapp 
    +description
    -userdesc
        -LquV8N1AJbRdhSKMA2T
            email: "bryan5@gmail.com"
            id: "870788464845"
            name: "bry5"
            pass: "123456"
            phone: "484854484546"
```

This is my logcat

```
2019-10-17 16:20:11.208 11014-11014/? I/ample.rsolveap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-10-17 16:20:11.226 11014-11014/? E/ample.rsolveap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

2019-10-17 16:20:11.226 11014-11014/? W/ample.rsolveap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86

2019-10-17 16:20:11.583 11014-11049/com.example.rsolveapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

2019-10-17 16:20:11.596 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 0dkRQhKR1rQBcAUVYcULtI0C4zN2 ).

2019-10-17 16:20:11.598 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId is not linked. Skipping initialization.

2019-10-17 16:20:11.598 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.

2019-10-17 16:20:11.599 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement is not linked. Skipping initialization.

2019-10-17 16:20:11.599 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful

2019-10-17 16:20:11.593 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:41): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6749 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c130,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.example.rsolveapp

2019-10-17 16:20:11.608 11014-11056/com.example.rsolveapp D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.

2019-10-17 16:20:11.608 11014-11056/com.example.rsolveapp W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)

2019-10-17 16:20:11.619 11014-11056/com.example.rsolveapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so

2019-10-17 16:20:11.620 11014-11056/com.example.rsolveapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so

2019-10-17 16:20:11.622 11014-11056/com.example.rsolveapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

2019-10-17 16:20:11.639 11014-11051/com.example.rsolveapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

2019-10-17 16:20:11.646 11014-11051/com.example.rsolveapp I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.

2019-10-17 16:20:11.646 11014-11051/com.example.rsolveapp I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation

2019-10-17 16:20:11.673 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp W/ample.rsolveap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)

2019-10-17 16:20:11.673 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp W/ample.rsolveap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)

2019-10-17 16:20:11.728 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.

2019-10-17 16:20:11.728 11014-11014/com.example.rsolveapp D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.

2019-10-17 16:20:11.750 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...

2019-10-17 16:20:11.752 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0

2019-10-17 16:20:11.752 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe151a180: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4

2019-10-17 16:20:11.769 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe151a180: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe150f480)

2019-10-17 16:20:11.771 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da

2019-10-17 16:20:11.771 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da

2019-10-17 16:20:11.782 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported

2019-10-17 16:20:11.785 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000

2019-10-17 16:20:11.785 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff807000 size 0x2000

2019-10-17 16:20:11.794 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe151a180: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe150f480)

2019-10-17 16:20:11.813 11014-11054/com.example.rsolveapp D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
```

This is my User class

```
package com.example.rsolveapp;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable{
private String email;
private String name, pass, id, phone;
private String key;

public User(){

}

public String getKey(){
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key){
    this.key=key;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email=email;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public String getPass(){
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass){
    this.pass=pass;
}

public String getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id){
    this.id=id;
}

public String getPhone(){
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone){
    this.phone=phone;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return " "+email+"/n"+
            " "+name+"/n"+
            " "+pass+"/n"+
            " "+id+"/n"+
            " "+phone;
}

public User(String Remail, String Rname, String Rpass, String Rid, String Rphone){
    email=Remail;
    name=Rname;
    pass=Rpass;
    id=Rid;
    phone=Rphone;
}
}
```

EDIT : this is my activity right now

```
public class RsolverAccount extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView showEmail;
private static final String TAG = RsolverAccount.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rsolveraccount);

    setWidget();
    showData();
}

private void showData () {

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(firebaseUser != null) {
        String email = firebaseUser.getEmail();
        Log.d(TAG, email);
    }

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("sraboetapp").child("userdesc").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            showEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
}

public void setWidget() {
    showEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showEmail);
}
}
```

This is the error i get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rsolveapp, PID: 13698
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.rsolveapp.User.getEmail()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.rsolveapp.RsolverAccount$1.onDataChange(RsolverAccount.java:45)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace to solve the issue and database snapshot.

Comment: add logcat here

Comment: Did you follow the necessary steps in order to fully integrate  Firebase into your app? i.e. this (https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and then this (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start)?

Comment: @SimonMayrshofer yes i did, i can save data into firebase and show all of it, but i wanted to show data only for the currently logged in user

Comment: @JasonChrislie whats the error you get? can you share the error log? Is it a NullPointerException or what is it that makes your App crash? Also what does your "User" file look like? can you share it..?

Comment: @SimonMayrshofer i get a null pointer exception Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference

Comment: @JasonChrislie could you also please include your `User.java` code?

Comment: @JasonChrislie i m not entirely sure, but I wonder if your constructor might be at issue here.. you should check out this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114944/why-we-need-an-empty-constructor-to-passing-save-a-data-from-firebase - and just to double check: your database does have the data in it and you are expecting an object to be received when you get the data snapshot?

Comment: @SimonMayrshofer yes, i'm trying to show the current logged in user detail data from database into that activity

Comment: @JasonChrislie Ahh hold on, try this: `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userdesc").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());` - does that work?

Comment: i'm still getting this error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.rsolveapp.User.getEmail()' on a null object reference"

Comment: You tried this before right? `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userdesc").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());`

Comment: yes i do, tried everything everyone suggest here

Comment: okay, i m sorry, i feel for you, dont get frustrated, you ll figure this out soon enough. I would recommend you to review this page and try to set up a new `User.java`, very cleanly following the on this page here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write. I do wonder for example if it is a problem that you have a constructor with the arguments `(String Remail, String Rname, String Rpass, String Rid, String Rphone)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you are getting the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()'

Because your `firebaseAuth` object is `null`. You did not initialize it. To solve this, simply add the following line of code:

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

As the first line in your `showData()` method.

**Edit:**

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(firebaseUser != null) {
    String email = firebaseUser.getEmail();
    Log.d(TAG, email);
}
```

Comment: now i get this following error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.rsolveapp.User.getEmail()' on a null object reference".

Comment: In that case, your `FirebaseUser` object is `null`. Simply check for nullity. Does it work now?

Comment: how to do that sir ?

Comment: after adding that line of code into my show data method, the apps still crash with the same error

Comment: Please add it to your question the code that you are using now and the entire error.

Comment: That's a totally different error that has nothing to do with the initial error. You get that error at this line: `showEmail.setText(user.getEmail());` which means that the user object is `null`. Make sure that you get that user object from the correct reference. If find hard time in doing that, please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.