# The RecyclerView doesn't activate, and I was wondering why

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I've been writing code for most of my app myself, yet when it came to using `RecyclerView`, I came to a halt. From there I was following a tutorial, yet when I try to use the program, the `RecycclerView` doesn't work. I am getting a message:

> LessonPost does not define a no-argument constructor.

Adapter class **LessonRecyclerAdaptor.java**

```java
    public class LessonRecyclerAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LessonRecyclerAdaptor.ViewHolder> {

    public List<LessonPost> lesson_list;

    public LessonRecyclerAdaptor (List<LessonPost> lesson_list) {

        this.lesson_list = lesson_list;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lesson_single_layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String desc_data = lesson_list.get(position).getDescription();

        holder.setDescriptionText(desc_data);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lesson_list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;

        private TextView recycler_description;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }
        public void setDescriptionText(String text){

            recycler_description = mView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_description);
            recycler_description.setText(text);

        }
    }
}
```

Model class **LessonPost** (from where the list gets its values)

```java
public class LessonPost {

    private String userID;
    private String Lesson_name;
    private String Lesson_image;
    private String Lesson_description;

    public LessonPost(String userID, String lessonName, String imageURL, String description) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.Lesson_name = lessonName;
        this.Lesson_image = imageURL;
        this.Lesson_description = description;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getLessonName() {
        return Lesson_name;
    }

    public void setLessonName(String lessonName) {
        this.Lesson_name = lessonName;
    }

    public String getLesson_imageL() {
        return Lesson_image;
    }

    public void setLesson_image(String imageURL) {
        this.Lesson_image = imageURL;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Lesson_description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String Lesson_description) {
        this.Lesson_description = Lesson_description;
    }
}
```

And the invocation from Main

```
lesson_list_main = findViewById(R.id.lesson_list_view);
    lesson_list = new ArrayList<>();
    lessonRecyclerAdaptor = new LessonRecyclerAdaptor(lesson_list);

    lesson_list_main.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    lesson_list_main.setAdapter(lessonRecyclerAdaptor);

    if (firestoreCheck.collection("Lessons").get() == null) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no lessons yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } else {

        firestoreCheck.collection("Lessons").document(userID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    firestoreCheck.collection("Lessons").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                            for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                    LessonPost lessonPostMain = doc.getDocument().toObject(LessonPost.class);
                                    lesson_list.add(lessonPostMain);

                                    lessonRecyclerAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }

                            }

                        }
                    });

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error hah ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the recyclerView but your database.

> The fields of the class will be filled in using reflection. But you cannot create a "default" object (meaning: with no fields pre-filled) without a constructor. Firebase cannot figure out on its own what your constructor does, so that's why you need an empty constructor (Source: [Why we need an empty Constructor to passing/save a Data From Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114944/why-we-need-an-empty-constructor-to-passing-save-a-data-from-firebase))

Answer (score 0):

@Charlie is right, firebase uses an empty constructor b/c of reflection. You need to do something like

```java
public class LessonPost {

   // first constructor, used by firebase
   public LessonPost() {
     // ... empty constructor
   }

   // second constructor, used in another place of your app
   public LessonPost(String userID, String lessonName, String imageURL, String description) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.Lesson_name = lessonName;
        this.Lesson_image = imageURL;
        this.Lesson_description = description;
    }   

}
```