# Error Trying to retrieve data from firebase database using android recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve data from my firebase database using android RecyclerView. Every time I run my app to test it I get a message saying that My app has stopped. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I looked on the Logcat to see what the error is but its only telling me what line the error is in but its not explaining why its an error. Can some please help me out here. Here is my code below

```
 //UserInformation.java

    public class UserInformation {

    public String bname;
    public String address;
    public String phone;

    public UserInformation(String bname, String address, String phone) {
        this.bname = bname;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }



    public String getBname() {
        return bname;
    }

    public void setBname(String bname) {
        this.bname = bname;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}


//Myadapter.java

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<UserInformation> users;

    public MyAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<UserInformation> u){

        context=c;
        users=u;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.biz.setText(users.get(position).getBname());
        holder.address.setText(users.get(position).getAddress());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        TextView biz,address;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            biz=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.biz_name);
            address=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.biz_address);
        }
    }
}

//MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {


    DatabaseReference rootRef;
    MenuItem menuItem;
    RecyclerView recycler;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    ArrayList<UserInformation> list;
    MyAdapter adapter;






   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_feed);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);



        menuItem=(MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.item_sign_in);




       mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);


       recycler=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
       recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));




//database reference pointing to root of database
       rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");




       rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                  list=new ArrayList<UserInformation>();

                  for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                      UserInformation uuu=dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                      list.add(uuu);

                  }
              }

               adapter=new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,list);
               recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });




       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
               != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           // Permission is not granted
           // Should we show an explanation?
           if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
               // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
               // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
               // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

               new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                       .setTitle("Required Location Permission")
                       .setMessage("You have to give this permission to access this feature")
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                       new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                       MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                               dialogInterface.dismiss();
                           }
                       })
                       .create()
                       .show();


           } else {
               // No explanation needed; request the permission
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                       new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                       MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

               // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
               // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
               // result of the request.
           }
       } else {
           // Permission has already been granted
           mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                   .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                           // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                           if (location != null) {
                               // Logic to handle location object
                               Double latittude = location.getLatitude();
                               Double longitude = location.getLongitude();





                               //user_location.setText("Latitude = "+latittude + "\nLongitude = " + longitude);
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission has been granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                           }
                       }
                   });



       }


//Firebase database
```

[image]

//Error log

[image]

Comment: Please post your database structure and stacktrace

Comment: @Ashish I just did right now take a look

Comment: @GCode22 show your error log.

Comment: @frankenstein I just added it

Comment: Error is clearing pointing that you need to define default constructor... just add `public UserInformation(){..}` in `UserInformation` class. For more information [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114944/why-we-need-an-empty-constructor-to-passing-save-a-data-from-firebase)

Comment: @ShadowDroid you were right. That was the problem. Its working now. Thank man. Can you add this as the answer so I can check it.

Comment: Sorry GCode22, Question with similar problem exist, and it has been already answer. I am glad that I was able to help you but I will not post it answer. Kindly accept answer posted by other. Just a small advice, always first get the error stacktrace and use it to understand your problem.

Comment: @ShadowDroid thanks for the advice, I will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an empty `constructor` in your `classmodel`.

Just add this.

```
     UserInformation(){ }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your **UserInformation** class variable name  and firebase name is different. 
 you must use same variable for class mapping

```
 public class UserInformation {

       public String   businesname;
        public String   address;
       public String   phonenumber;

     // add empty constructor necessary for firebase
    //  add 2nd constructor(as per your need)  
   // add getter and setter

  }
```

Use camelcase for naming variables.

Comment: I did what you said and I still have the same problem

Comment: your error log shows that u did not added a empty public constructor. and rename all variable and recreate getter/setter.