# Firebase DatabaseException "Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My Database Structure]Im getting a Firebase DatabaseException "Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.firebasedeneme.Title "

Im having tihs error by getValue()

```
a = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(e.getText().toString()).exists()){
                            String username = e.getText().toString();
                            User user = dataSnapshot.child(username).getValue(User.class);
```

There i save the datas

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(user.getUsername()).setValue(user);
```

My User class looks like

```
public class User implements Comparable<User>,Serializable{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String title;
    private int xp;
    private int score;
    private int level;
    private int image;
    private Stack<Title> titles;
    public User() {}
    public User(String username, String password, String title, int xp, int score, int level, int image, Stack<Title> titles){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.level = level;
        this.score = score;
        this.xp = xp;
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
        this.titles = titles;
    }
```

My Title Class looks like

```
public class Title {
    private int titleno;
    private String title;
    public Title(int titleno, String title){
        this.title = title;
        this.titleno = titleno;
    }
    public int getTitleno(){
        return this.titleno;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Mateo Hervas's answer is correct. Your `titles` property is a List and not a `Stack`.

Comment: I tried Mateo Hervas' solution, but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is because the type of Title is a `Stack` and in Firebase you have an Array. Change your Title variable to be:

```
private ArrayList<Title> titles;
```

If that doesn't work, can you also add your Title model class to the question? That way we might be able to help better.

Comment: It didnt work.I added my Title model to the question, thanks for the advice.

Comment: are you getting the same error? or is it another one? I am seing your model and your databse structure, and i think the error is because you should change your `titleno` variable to `Long`. your value is 10 digits long and thats the max that an int can hold, change it to long and let me know so I can update the answer

Comment: Im still getting the same error.Yes, i tried to change it to long but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue while fetching data from the firebase realtime database. It is required to add default constructor in all the model classes. So you also need to add default constructor in your Title class similarly that you have added in your User class.

```
public Title(){}
```

Refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114944/why-we-need-an-empty-constructor-to-passing-save-a-data-from-firebase#:~:text=Firebase%20cannot%20figure%20out%20on,to%20fill%20in%20using%20reflection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114944/why-we-need-an-empty-constructor-to-passing-save-a-data-from-firebase#:%7E:text=Firebase%20cannot%20figure%20out%20on,to%20fill%20in%20using%20reflection.)

Comment: In kotlin, i'm using data class. Will there be any issue in reading Firebase object into this model class? I'm getting the following Fatal Exception: f9.c Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type   @Keep
data class GraphConfig(
    val xAxis: XAxis = XAxis(),
    val yAxis: YAxis = YAxis()
)